# Is "com.google.android.tts" available on all android devices running api 21 and above?

Tags: android, text-to-speech

I am using Google TTS in my app that support api 21 and above to read words. I have passed the third parameter of TTS function. In my case, what are some other steps that needs to be done to support almost all android devices that runs api >=21 to read text? I have tested some Samsung devices that is works well, but not sure if it works on all devices.

```
textToSpeech = new TextToSpeech(getContext(), i -> {
        if (i != TextToSpeech.ERROR) {
            textToSpeech.setLanguage(Locale.US);
        }
    },"com.google.android.tts");
```